# SSH port forwarding with reverse proxy

Tags: iis, ssh, reverse-proxy, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have the following scenario.

[image: Infrastructure]

1. At my workplace a Web Application is running on port 5000 and 5001 (with https).
2. There is a little V-Server running OpenSSH + IIS (or NGINGX on Linux)
3. I want to access that service through a HTTPS connection with specified domain.
4. The V-Server should handle all the SSL Certificate stuff. (We use ACME right now)

I know there are services like **ngrok** that do exactly fit our needs, but we need many connections, which will get too expensive for us.

Connecting to the V-Server via SSH is the easy part. Opening the port forwarding from localhost:5000 to remote:5000 is also easy.
Now there comes the tricky part. Is it possible to configure e.g. the IIS Server to serve an endpoint (http://mypage.com and https://mypage.com), manage the certificate and transfer the incoming request to the localhost:5000 tunnel? Or is there a IIS extensions that does exactly this operation?

**Disclaimer**
mypage.com is just a placeholder

Comment: IIS was not designed for such scenarios, so you won't see any built-in support. There isn't a well known IIS extension for that purpose either. You will have to use search engines to locate what are the options for you, or talk to such server providers as many of them (AWS/Azure/GCP for example) might know what solutions are out there. Stack Overflow is not for service recommendation.

Comment: Your site is hosted on the localhost port. you will not be able to access that localhost site from the internet. so it is not possible to achieve your requirement using the IIS and I am not aware of any extension that could help to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Thank you two for your replies. I already had the fear that IIS was not capable...